# Using .htaccess is giving 500 error but working for file

Tags: .htaccess

I am not an expert using `.htaccess` but here is my scenario:

1. My `.htaccess` is in the root.
2. The only content is below.
3. To access the `pdf` file is working fine but not when I am trying to access the file with parameters that is going to return data or send data.
4. I know I am missing something but what?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^admin$ login.php
    RewriteRule ^admin-system/balance/get$ source/Support/Action.php?action=balance-get
    RewriteRule ^admin-system/balance/list$ source/Support/Action.php?action=balance-list
    RewriteRule ^admin-system/balance/set$ source/Support/Action.php?action=balance-set

    # This one is working fine. 
    RewriteRule ^admin-system/terms$ app/helper/files/term.pdf

    Options +Indexes
</IfModule>
```

Comment: What URLs are you requesting? And what is the desired result? "access the file with parameters" - None of the directives you've posted do anything with a request that contains parameters?

Answer (score 0):

HTTP 500 - when talking about htaccess - is a syntax error. IMHO, just remove the following line:

```
Options +Indexes
```

It's highly possible, that Options is not allowed there - the apache error log will give you a clue about it.

Comment: There is no problem with that `Options` directive in the context it is used. But yes, the OP should check the details of the error that triggered the 500 response.

Comment: @MrWhite: I know, it's valid there, but will throw HTTP500 is 'Allow Override' is set to 'None' in the VHOST config.

Comment: No it won't. If `AllowOverride: None` is set (and `AllowOverrideList` is not) then the entire `.htaccess` file will simply be ignored - no error. But anyway, we know that the `.htaccess` file is at least _parsed_ successfully, since the OP has stated that access to "the `pdf` file is working fine".